# Doctrine : getting related entity records is fetching object, get array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have related a loan table with the bids table, where single loan can have many bids. When i try to fetch a loan i should get bid details but i'm unable to get that.

My entities are:

```
class Loan extends Base {
   //....
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bid", mappedBy="loan")
    */
   protected $bids;
   //....
}

class Bid extends Base {
   //....
   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Loan", inversedBy="bids")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="loan_id", referencedColumnName="id",
                onDelete="CASCADE")
    *
    */
     protected $loan;

   //....
}
```

And My output is(see the bids in the loan details):

```
{
  "loan_amount_required": 30000,
  "interest_rate": 3,
  "loan_duration": 1,
  "loan_validity": 5,
  "status": "active",
  "loan_created": "2015-11-27 12:35:56",
  "user": {
    "fname": "",
    "lname": "",
    "email": "",
    "password": "",
    "is_active": true,
    "random_number": ,
    "role": "user",
    "balance": 0,
    "last_seen": "........",
    "notify_me": true,
    "id": 34
  },
  "bids": [
    {}
  ],
  "id": 71
}
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: Start by checking your database to see if your bid table has the expected loan ids.  I suspect you will find them to be null because Bid::setLoan is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Loan constructor :

```
// ...
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Loan extends Base
{
    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bids = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```